# How to use NSNumberFormatter to format numbers to a NSString of limited characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

For example, a calculator can only display a maximum of 9 characters.

```
          1/2  ->        0.5
          2/3  ->  0.6666667
          3/4  ->       0.75
      20000/3  ->  6666.6667
123456x123456  ->  1.5241E10
                   ---------
                   123456789
```

Comment: What about negative numbers? Does the `-` count as a character?

Comment: @Rich I can afford one character of error, so `-` can be counted or not counted.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`setMaximumSignificantDigits:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumSignificantDigits%3a) on the `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
 [numberFormatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
 [numberFormatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:9];
 [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
```

For whole number integers with more than 9 digits, there's not much you can do except use the `NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle`.

After checking this with a small program (see below) - you're still going to have issues with multi digit exponents. You might be better off having multiple `NSNumberFormatter`s and check what the number is before displaying it. I'll have a quick play around and update this when I have a more robust solution.

(Directly from CodeRunner copy and paste)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static void test(NSNumber *n)
{
    NSNumberFormatter *f = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [f setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
    [f setMaximumSignificantDigits:9];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
    NSString *s = [f stringFromNumber:n];
    NSLog(@"%@ -> %@ (%lu)", n, s, [s length]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        test(@(1.0/2));
        test(@(2.0/3));
        test(@(3.0/4));
        test(@(20000.0/2));
        test(@(123456*123456));
        test(@(0.000000000001));
        test(@(123456789.000000000001));
        test(@(12345.9999999999999));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2014-04-24 12:33:01.480 Untitled[3006:507] 0.5 -> 5E-1 (4)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.481 Untitled[3006:507] 0.6666666666666666 -> 6.66666667E-1 (13)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.481 Untitled[3006:507] 0.75 -> 7.5E-1 (6)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.482 Untitled[3006:507] 10000 -> 1E4 (3)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.482 Untitled[3006:507] -1938485248 -> -1.93848525E9 (13)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.483 Untitled[3006:507] 1e-12 -> 1E-12 (5)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.483 Untitled[3006:507] 123456789 -> 1.23456789E8 (12)
2014-04-24 12:33:01.484 Untitled[3006:507] 12346 -> 1.2346E4 (8)
```

Comment: You need `setMaximumFractionDigits` not significant digits. 0.000000000001 has a significant digits count of 1.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin Setting maximum fraction digits will not work for numbers such as `12345.9999999999999`, as then the string will be over 9 characters long. Using significant digits and scientific style will mean that `0.000000000001` will be converted to `1E-12`

Comment: but scientific style will switch even 0.01 to 1E-2. I think OP wants full precision unless the total digits > 9

Comment: I know - I was correcting your above comment - `setMaximumFractionDigits` would not always work.

Comment: The OP needs to use `NSDecimalNumber`s too...!

Comment: Probably I need to setup a few conditions (e.g. greater than or smaller than certain value) and switch to a different formatter. p.s. thanks for introducing CodeRunner, sounds like an interesting app.

Comment: @ohho Its a great app for quick code mock up cases like this. In the long run functionality like you want _oozes_ a need for Unit Tests! :D